# Explain time Conversion to minutes and hours

Tags: ruby, time

Can someone please explain to me how this works?

```
While minutes >=60...
```

How does Ruby know how many hours there are???

```
def time_conversion(minutes)
  hours = 0

  while minutes >= 60
    hours = hours + 1
    minutes = minutes - 60
  end
  return hours
end
```

Comment: The while loop is calculating them. Is it the basic math you're having trouble with, or the ruby code?

Comment: This is some very flawed code. Where did you find it? `hours, minutes = minutes / 60, minutes % 60` does the job just the same.

Comment: "How does Ruby know how many hours there are?" – It doesn't. That's what that code is computing.

Comment: Not having trouble with the math but the code itself. I don't understand how Ruby knows there are 60 mins in an hour. There's no code that explicitly states 60 mins in an hour.

Comment: @imperfectskillz: Ruby doesn't know. It's in the code. Didn't you see the `60` in the code? Twice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this simple way:

```
def time_conversion(minutes)
  hours = (minutes/60 % 60)
  return hours
end

> time_conversion(125)
#=> 2 
> time_conversion(165)
#=> 2
```

Now let's convert it to **`"HH:MM"`**

```
def time_conversion(minutes)
  hh_mm = [minutes / 60 % 60, minutes % 60].map { |t| t.to_s.rjust(2,'0') }.join(':')
  return hh_mm
end

>  time_conversion(125)
#=> "02:05" 
>  time_conversion(165)
#=> "02:45"
```

Comment: @imperfectskillz : If this answer helpful to you to resolved your problem then you can mark(tick) it as answered

Answer (score 2):

Well, walk through a few examples.

If `minutes` is 125, how many hours should be returned?
`125 - 60 - 60 = 5`. There's two 60's, so **two** hours.

If `minutes` is 65, how many hours should be returned?
`65 - 60 = 5`. There's only one 60, so **one** hour.

The Ruby code does the same thing, counting how many times it can subtract 60 until it cannot subtract any more (i.e., subtracting another 60 would result in a negative number). It does this with a `while` loop.

The two lines inside the `while` loop:

```
hours = hours + 1
minutes = minutes - 60
```

update the `hours` and `minutes` variables just like we did in our examples. When `minutes` is less than 60, we stop and return how many total hours we counted.

Comment: I just don't understand how ruby knows the correlation between minutes and hours. how does it know that there are 60 minutes in an hour?

Comment: @imperfectskillz We told it so by writing 60.

Comment: where does it say hours = 60 mins?

Comment: It doesn't. Ruby doesn't "know" anything. Computers are simple machines that we write algorithms for to do useful work. This algorithm repeatedly subtracts 60 from the number of minutes because *we* know that there are 60 minutes in an hour. The computer doesn't know this, only blindly doing what we tell it to do.